# Require specific Magento 2 Github commit with composer

Tags: magento2, composer, github

There are some explanations on Stackexchange on how to require a specific commit with composer, for example these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878984/can-i-pull-a-specific-commit-with-composer
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314381/how-to-correctly-require-a-specific-commit-in-composer-so-that-it-would-be-avail

However, I can't figure out how to do this for the Magento 2 repository. I want to have this commit in my repository: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/beeae93d25ca4a35e7b4879f9447cc82119872aa

**What I have tried so far**

**1.)** `composer require magento/magento2 "dev-develop#beeae93"`

*Error:*

> The requested package magento/magento2 could not be found in any
>   version

**2.)** `composer require magento/product-community-edition "dev-develop#beeae93"`

*Error:*

> The requested package magento/product-community-edition dev-developer#beeae93 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.8, [...]`

**My composer.json file**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.0.10",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "foomanartifacts": {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "vendor/fooman/packages"
        },
        "iways_paypalplus": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.8",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "iways/module-pay-pal-plus": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.3.*",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The Magento 2 composer repositories are maintained separately from the development repository in GitHub.

### That means:

- there is one repository per module (`magento/product-community-edition` is a **meta package**)
- the commit hashes are not the same
- only released versions are in the composer repository

The consequence is that if you want to use any pre-alpha version of Magento 2, you cannot use composer but you will have to use the **contributor installation** by cloning the repository, as described here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html **This is not meant for production**

> If you clone the Magento 2 GitHub repository, you cannot use the Magento software in a production environment. You cannot have a live store that accepts orders and so on.

### Alternative solution

To address your actual problem, namely include certain bug fixes in your installation, you can use a different approach.

I can recommend the [symlinker-pro](https://github.com/staempfli/symlinker-pro) tool, as presented at https://speakerdeck.com/mhauri/mm17de-magento-2-in-production

It allows you to create a module with fixes in any files which will overwrite the core files with symlinks.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks. Why would you use the symlinker-pro tool instead of creating a preference for the class I want to change in a Magento extension?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer in cases where it is not possible (abstract classes, non-php files)